# Ubuntu installation on i5-2430m possible?

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

I want to install Ubuntu 13.10 in my VirtualBox.  When I try it with the 64-bit version, I get this error:

```
This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU
```

Ii have an Intel core i5-2430m. as far as I know, it's an 64-bit CPU, and I tried it with the 32-bit version and got this error:

```
This kernel requires the following features not present on the CPU: PAE
```

So what should I do now to make it run?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

That's because your VirtualBox emulates a 32bit non-PAE cpu. You should look into your BIOS to activate a feature called "virtualization" or something like this. 
Maybe you should also look into your VirtualBox settings, see if you can enable another CPU emulation.

Your CPU is 64bit capable, maybe your VirtualBox isn't